# Host ShinyApp from own (Linux) server and own domain

Tags: r, shiny-server

I have programmed a Shiny WebApp and would now like to deploy it myself. So far I have made it available at shinyapps.io. For this I have already set up my own server (a virtual machine running on a datacenter), installed CentOS Server and bought my own domain. Likewise, I have already installed ShinyServer.

However, now I do not really know how to proceed.
In forums I have found various possibilities, which I can not really understand. Therefore I would like to ask here, which possibility is the simplest to provide a Shiny WebApp from the own server under the own domain. This should work without additional costs.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I you have already installed Shinyserver on the CentOs -instance i would advise you to

1. test if the installation is running properly by checking if the sample app’s are running:

- go to a webbrowser on your local machine http://"your-server-address":3838/sample-apps
- the test apps should be displayed here , if not:

```
$ sudo systemctl start shiny-server
```

- check again

2. copy (scp or clone from git ) your App.R onto the server and put it inside a subdirectory of the /srv/shiny-server/ - directory
3. check if the app is displayed and works properly (often dependencies are missing) on the server port 3838:

```
http://"your-server-address":3838/myApp
```

4: read the

- documentation: https://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/
- quick start guide: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/shiny-server.html

Comment: http://"your-server-address":3838 is working, but http://"your-server-address":3838/sample-apps shows me: An error has occured, The application failed to start. The Application exited during initialization.

Comment: sounds like some packages might not be installed (maybe shiny) . you can check the error logs at /var/  (/var/log/shiny-server.log) and /var/log/shiny-server/*.log or the user has not the right permission see : https://community.rstudio.com/t/3838-sample-apps-hello-page-is-not-working-fine-it-is-giving-error-the-application-exited-during-initialization/23834/2

Comment: Now I have got it right. It was due to the access rights. (Whereas I still can not open the folder `sample-apps`). I copied my .rmd file into the folder and now I can open it in the web browser: http://"your-server-address":3838/myApp.Rmd

Comment: What would be the next step to make the ShinyAPp available under my own domain?